# Change the default browser which Kopete opens when you click a link?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, kopete

I have FireFox as my desktop's default browser (Ubuntu/Gnome 9.10) and most applications open links into FF readily enough, including Choqok (a KDE twitter client).

But Kopete insists on opening Konqueror - which is annoying as it takes an age to load, while FF is almost always open an simply needs a new tab.

I've checked though the preferences of Kopete, and can't seem to find anything to make it use FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use KDE's "System Settings" tool by launching ***systemsettings*** or find it on your menu. Then under **Default Applications** you'll find a **Web Browser** option.

OR

Edit ~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals
and alter the line with **BrowserApplication[$e]** to read:

BrowserApplication[$e]=!firefox

That should do it, and this assumes you are using KDE4.

Comment: hi - i'm running Kopete on Gnome...

Comment: Right, but Kopete will still need a base KDE install to run so that file should exist for you, even if you don't have systemsettings. Your config dir might be ~/.kde4 also.

Comment: this is going to sound strange - but i think i did it... and i think i did it following your instructions. but that was a couple of weeks ago, and now i can't find how i did it or where it is set...

Answer (score 3):

A kind of SleighBoy's solution works for me under 10.04 LTS.
I had the same problem (wanted to open chrome instead FF). I added lines

> [General]
>   BrowserApplication=google-chrome

at the end of kdeglobals and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Create a `.desktop` file.
   Open your text editor and paste this to the editor and save it as `firefox.desktop`:

   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Name=Firefox
   Exec=firefox %u
   Type=Application
   Icon=firefox
2. Move the `firefox.desktop` file to `/usr/share/applications/`
3. Run:

   $ xdg-mime default firefox.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
   $ xdg-mime default firefox.desktop x-scheme-handler/https
   $ xdg-mime default firefox.desktop text/html